# EF 6 Code First one column is not created

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I am using EF 6 Code First, I don't understand why one column is not created for a property of my Model.

Here is the first class :

```
    public class Original
    {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; private set; }
    public Historique Historique { get; private set; }
    public Traduction Traduction { get; private set; }
    }
```

And here is the second class :

```
   public class Traduction
   { 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Utilisateur Traducteur { get; private set; }
    public Original Original { get; private set; }
    public string Content { get; private set; }
   }
```

EF doesn't create the FK column for Traduction and Original. (The Traduction table doesn't contains a FK column for Original and vice versa) but it perfectly creates all the other column and FKs.

I am playing with Fluent API to set up the relationships. I have tried both to rely on the automatic conventions, and to explicitly configure the relation with :

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Original>().HasRequired(o => o.Traduction).WithRequiredPrincipal(t=>t.Original).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But the columns are still not created.

Thank you for your help

**Update**

I don't know if it is useful but I would like to add one information, my Dbset are defined like this in the context class :

```
public DbSet<Traduction> Traductions { get; set; }
public DbSet<Original> Originaux { get; set; }
```

"Originaux" if the French plural for "Originals". However I have noticed that the Table created by EF is Named "Originals", and doesn't follow the name of the DbSet. I don't know, perhaps it might be a cause of the problem.

Comment: ID should be the foreign key column since you defined a 1:1 relationship. Also, EF does not name your table based on what you called the DbSet. It names it based on the plural of the entity type name. Original = Originals

Comment: Thank you for your help @Dismissile, what should I add then ?

Comment: you shouldn't need to add anything. If you look at ID in the database, it should be both a primary key and a foreign key in one table. It will be just the primary key in the other table. This is how a one to one relationship works in a database.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't have access to SQL Server MS right know, and since I'm using VS2010, I cannot access the table definition because it's hosted on MS Server 2012. But how is EF going to construct (for example) my Original objects, if it doesn't store the ID of the corresponding Traduction in a column ? 
I asked this question because I noticed that the Traduction property is left to null when I retrieve an object from the DB. After seeing that there is no Traduction_ID column in the DB I concluded that this was the cause of the problem.

Comment: Oh also, Original and Historique also have a 1:1 relationship and there is a Historique_ID column in the DB !

Comment: @Dismissile I've just understand the point you made about one-to-one relationships ! However for some reason the property are not populated when retrieved from the DB. But that's another issue for which I have opened an other question. You perfectly answered my queston concerning why no column was created. Thanks ! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Also for future readers,  a Foreign Key Column was created for the Historique property because the relationship was implictly set to one-to-many by EF. It wasn't actually a one-to-one relationship. When I manually configured the one-to-one relationship between Original/Traduction and Historique this column disappeared.

Comment: Post the answer that fixed your problem and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dismissile said, EF doesn't create an extra column to hold the foreign keys because it is a one-to-one relationship. This is a normal behaviour and nothing is actually wrong.